# Redirecting route53 purchased domain to s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I've just purchased a domain from Route 53 and created corresponding buckets in AWS s3. I've followed the instructions from: [Example: Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).

Let's say my custom domain is called `customdomain.com`.

I've created `customdomain.com` and `www.customdomain.com` buckets in s3 and allowed static website hosting on customdomain.com and enabled redirecting from www.customdomain.com to the customdomain.com bucket.

When I enter the endpoint for `customdomain.com` it works just fine, meaning my bucket policies are working correctly.

Next, in Route 53, I've set up Hosted Zone for `customdomain.com`.
I've also created a record set in that hosted zone with the name:
`customdomain.com`, type A, aliasing to customdomain.com's endpoint (which I chose from the dropdown menu). I left everything else as default then saved it. I added the record for www.customdomain.com but had it alias to customdomain.com

When I try to access customdomain.com, Chrome states that the site can't be reached.

Did I miss a step somewhere or does it take time for my site to be up due to DNS propagation or something?

Comment: How long ago did you purchase it? What are the TTLs on the DNS records? Have you tried it from other DNS servers (opendns, Google, from inside EC2)?

Comment: Okay, let's work through this one step at a time. Are you saying that it works via something like `customdomain.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`, but not via `customdomain.com`? And that your bucket is named exactly the same as the DNS name you wish to use (`customdomain.com`)?  And that you've created a Route 53 `ALIAS=YES` A-Record pointing to the bucket called `customdomain.com`?

Comment: May be you need add record DNS www IN CNAME domain.com , check your DNS.

Comment: @John, yes to all of your questions.

Comment: TEDDER I purchased it yesterday about 30 hours ago at the time of this comment. I have no idea about the others.  
JOHN, yes to all of your questions. I've followed all the steps in the link of my question except for one "Switching AWS to my DNS provider". I thought I don't need to do that as I purchased my domain straight from Route 53  
KUSH, isn't my DNS provider route 53 seeing how I purchased my domain name from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

Apparently, the domain's name servers weren't the same as my hosted zone's name servers